# nvidia driver 375.51 not working properly on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I updated nvidia drivers this morning, previous version was `375.26` which is the last working on my machine.

Now when I `nvidia-smi` **it just hangs indefinitely** and if I run a `tensorflow` code it throws

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:509] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
```

while if I run a stupid cuda program compiled with `nvcc` it just goes.

When I `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`, I have:

```
ii  nvidia-375                            375.51-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.51
ii  nvidia-375-dev                        375.51-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                       375.51-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                 375.51-0ubuntu1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                          0.8.2                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                       375.51-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Is anybody else facing this?
I found [this](http://forums.fast.ai/t/psa-ubuntu-16-04-apt-update-breaks-cuda-8-0/2086) for example, but didn't succeed.

### EDIT

I'm on an Azure instance, this is important, **see the answer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://askubuntu.com/a/910998/17099) fixes it.
It was a problem related to Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.4.0-75, as it came out from an answer given by Microsoft to a support request, this:

> Canonical appears to have recently released kernel 4.4.0-75 for Ubuntu 16.04 and this is having an adverse effect on Tesla GPUs on NC-series VMs. Installation of the 4.4.0-75 breaks the 8.0.61-1 version of the NVIDIA CUDA driver that’s currently recommended for use on these systems, resulting in nvidia-smi not showing the adapters and lspci returning an error similar to the following:
>
> `root@pd-nvtest2:~# lspci
>         lspci: Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/devices/2baf:00:00.0/resource: No such file or directory`

So run `apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic` - this will install a new kernel version as well - and then `update-grub`.

Then reboot and it should work!